# Replacing images using onerror depening on error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am trying to use `onerror` with an image but not to see if the images sources are good or not but to check if some other links are good.

I would like to use `onerror` to see if (let's say google.com) is good then it will show a green image but if google.com for some reason end up having 404 then it will show a red image. Below is a sample of my code and fiddle.

Any help will be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/w0xf3pc6/

```
<img src="http://greensportsalliance.org/images/darkGreenSquare.gif" 
                                                 onerror="imgError(this);"/>

function imgError(image) {
    image.onerror = "";
    image.src = "http://objects.chopard.com/media/catalog/category/bg-red-carpet.jpg";
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It works if you pick the “No wrap - in `<head>`” option under “Frameworks & Extensions” (second drop-down menu) at the left of JSFiddle. At least the image checking part…

Comment: What is the question here?  You're describing some aspects of what you're trying to do, but you don't tell us specifically what isn't working for you.

Comment: no an fiddle issue. What im trying to accomplish is add code in javscript which will in simple word check status external website to see if it's up and running if it's running then it will have green image but if the website has 404 then it will have red image.

Answer (score 0):

**It works fine here:**  try again in your project...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html>
  <head>
    <script>
function imgError(image) {
    image.onerror = "";
    image.src = "http://objects.chopard.com/media/catalog/category/bg-red-carpet.jpg";
    return true;
}
</script>
    </head>
  
<body>

<img src="image.gif" onerror="imgError(this);">



</body>
</html>
```